# I've been reading that it's possible to create a "mostly magnetic" wave, and I have a few questions

Tags: electromagnetism, radio, waves

Would it be possible with the "mostly magnetic wave" to have it behave in such a way that it would be undetectable by radio triangulation? I read about the monument at the CIA headquarters that was designed by an artist. Supposedly it's cryptography is very difficult to decipher, but some of it has been deciphered. One of the lines reads "It was transmitted magnetically undergrund". That's the actual spelling of the translation by the way - "Undergrund".

I've also read that waves that are mostly magnetic penetrate the ground far more deeply than a simple radio wave.

So my question is multi-faceted. Could waves that are mostly magnetic carry a signal of any kind better than a radio frequency generator, and if they're mostly magnetic would it follow that they'd be mostly undetectable to people trying to find the source of a radio transmission?

Comment: Might want to try this at [skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) fix the relationship between the electric and magnetic components of an electromagnetic wave travelling through any given medium, so there is no such thing as a "mostly magnetic wave" distinct from an ordinary EM wave.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this "mostly magnetic wave"?